# EUC-KR codec not available in Qt 4.8.1

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm trying to decode a string encoded with "ks_c_5601-1987" charset. Since Qt doesn't support it I'm trying to use "EUC-KR" (according to Qt documentation, this one is available). The problem is that QTextCodec doesn't show me this option available when I search with this code:

```
QTextCodec* codec;
qDebug()<<codec->availableCodecs();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a QTextCodec object.

Comment: You should be calling static functions properly: `qDebug() << QTextCodec::availableCodecs();`